# Sum of subset based on second vector

Tags: r

I got two vectors:

```
a <- c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6)
b <- c(T,F,T,F,T,T,F,F,F,T)
```

I would like to have a vector that tells me how many TRUEs there are in `b` for each unique value in `a`. (the second column)

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    3    0
[4,]    4    2
[5,]    5    0
[6,]    6    1
```

The best I can come up here with is using sapply:

```
sapply(unique(a), FUN = function(uniqueA, a, b) sum(b[a == uniqueA]), a = a, b = b)
```

This is fine, but for larger vectors it is rather slow. (I tried some subset variants.)

```
a <- sample(1:1000, 1e5, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(c(T,F), 1e5, replace = TRUE)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    subset = sapply(unique(a), FUN = function(uniqueA, a, b) sum(b[a == uniqueA]), a = a, b = b)
    , iN = sapply(unique(a), FUN = function(uniqueA, a, b) sum(a %in% uniqueA & b), a = a, b = b)
    , equal = sapply(unique(a), FUN = function(uniqueA, a, b) sum(a == uniqueA & b), a = a, b = b)
    , times = 5
)

Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 subset  389.1995  390.6002  413.6969  393.0396  445.6553  449.9897     5
     iN 2746.8407 2798.0462 2797.3155 2806.9477 2814.6317 2820.1110     5
  equal 1080.3430 1089.2507 1111.0267 1096.8082 1135.1957 1153.5358     5
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this faster?

Comment: `tapply(b, a, sum)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(b, list(a), sum)
```

For the fastest performance, I'd suggest a `data.table`. It will take longer to set up, but the performance should be quite good for larger amounts of data.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = a, b = b)
dt[,sum(b), by = a]
```

---

Speed test comparing (1) aggregate, (2) sapply, (3) data.table, (4) tapply:

```
  a <- sample(1:1000, 1e5, replace = TRUE)
  b <- sample(c(T,F), 1e5, replace = TRUE)

  summarize_dt <- function(x) {
    dt <- data.table(a = a, b = b)
    dt[,sum(b), by = a]
  }

  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    aggregate = aggregate(b, list(a), sum),
    sapply = sapply(unique(a), FUN = function(uniqueA, a, b) sum(b[a == uniqueA]), a = a, b = b),
    datatable = summarize_dt(),
    tapply = tapply(b, a, sum)
  )

      #expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
 #aggregate 130.995347 133.672041 141.404597 135.301762 137.199151 213.730345   100
    #sapply 335.344866 357.387474 394.432339 411.994214 425.604144 486.548520   100
 #datatable   1.540011   1.914712   2.430220   2.027578   2.239999   5.297593   100
    #tapply   3.075646   3.627395   4.719595   4.089434   5.934675   8.758332   100
```

Looks like `data.table` is the fastest by a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is quite a performance increase. `data.table` for me is not the way to go, since I want to use it within a function and don't want to force to use the package.

Answer (score 1):

This one maybe using `table` in base R:

```
t <- table(a[b])
z <- as.numeric(names(t))
rbind(unname(cbind(z, t)), cbind(setdiff(unique(a),z),0))

    # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    2    1
# [3,]    4    2
# [4,]    6    1
# [5,]    3    0
# [6,]    5    0
```

If you want those with non-zero number of `TRUE`'s, just `table(a[b])` would suffice.

Comment: A little shorter `cbind(unique(sort(a)), table(a, b)[,2])`.

Answer (score 1):

Or we can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(a, b) %>% 
       group_by(a) %>%
       summarise(b = sum(b))
```

---

A base R option would be

```
rowsum(+b, a)
```

Comment: The rowsum variant is actually really good, since I only need the vector and not the matrix. (Sorry, did ask the question incorrectly.) What does the '+' do?

Comment: @Georgery  The output matrix can be coerced to vector i.e. `c(rowsum(+b, a))`

Comment: Yeah, I know. Thanks. But the `+` - what does it do?

Comment: @Georgery  The `rowsum` doesn't take a logical vector as argument, so we had to coerce it to integer you can either use `+` to convert to binary or wrap with `as.integer` i.e. `rowsum(as.integer(b), a)`